# Maven ignore dependency if it cannot be found

Tags: java, maven

Basically, I have a maven dependency of a jar, that in reality is another jar patched.
Sadly, the patched jar cannot be on a maven repo, because that would go against the copyright, so instead it must be downloaded along with a patcher script, patched, and installed.

The thing is, the jar is not needed, and should be ignored if it is not found (like on a CI). It is only there so I can view the source code of the jar (which contains implementations of the interfaces/abstract classes in the jar I do use, which is public and has a maven repo).

Is there any way to tell maven to ignore the dependency if it cannot be found?

Comment: This could help ? https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html

Comment: That looks exactly like it, thank you so much!

Comment: @HarryCoder I don't think you can build without the `<optional>` dependency present.

Comment: Yep my CI still doesn't build.